# Boundedness of the norms of a sequence in $l^p$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

If $(x_n)$ is a sequence in $l^p$ $(1< p< \infty)$ and $\sum_{j=1}^\infty x_n(j)y(j)$ tends to $0$ as $n$ tends to infinity for every $y \in l ^q$ $(\frac{1}{p} +\frac{1}{q} =1)$. Then how to prove that $\sup_n \|x_n\|_p < \infty$? 
Note that $x_n(j)$ and $y(j)$ mean the $j$-th members of the sequences $x_n$ and $y$ respectively.

I was trying using particular $y$, but that was not helping.

Answer (score 0):

The dual of $l^p$ is $l^q$, and $\sum\limits_{j=1}^{\infty}{x_n(j)y(j)}\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$ actually means that $\langle y^*,x_n \rangle\to 0,\forall y^*\in (l^p)^*=l^q$ (the equality is not literal) which means that $x_n\rightharpoonup 0$ (weakly) in $l^p$. But all weakly convergent sequences are bounded, so $\sup\limits_{n\in\mathbb N}\|x_n\|_p < \infty$

Comment: Sir, can we have more direct proof for this?

Comment: @akansha: Yes, there is one.  Do you know the uniform boundedness principle?

Comment: @PhoemueX I tried using uniform boundedness principle by constructing linear operators $T_n$ on $l^q$ as $T_n(y)= \sum_{j=1}^\infty x_n(j)y(j)$. The only thing which I am not getting is how to deduce our conclusion by using the uniform boundedness of the sequence $(T_n)$ ?

Comment: @akansha: Use that $\|x_n \|_{\ell^p} = \sup_{\|y\|_{\ell^q} \leq 1} |\langle x_n , y\rangle| = \|T_n\|$.